# What is the first instance of a disaster movie coming true?

Tags: cinema-history

Think movies like [Twister](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117998/), [Dante's Peak](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118928/) and [Hard Rain](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120696/) as general examples, but feel free to expand on them. Avoid movies like [The Day After Tomorrow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0319262/) because they're not as clear-cut and may lead to a discussion about global warming rather than answering the question.

Note: specifically looking for the **FIRST** instance of the movie coming out before the event occurred, not **ANY** instance of the movie coming first.

Comment: I'll answer this question on 22-12-12

Comment: @TylerShads If it's good, I'll upvote your answer on 23-12-12.

Comment: @TylerShads If you answer it on 22-12-12, it wouldn't be a good answer, would it?

Comment: Too bad this site is limited to TV and movies, because the Wreck of the Titan was a good example of a written story that seemed to come true.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futility,_or_the_Wreck_of_the_Titan

Comment: Though not strictly prophetic, this [answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/1523/304) to the question [Align Actor Names](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1520/304) reminded me of this question.

Comment: Yes and I'm never paying Taxes. Again. Ever!

Comment: [Discussion on Meta about this question](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/335/this-just-doesnt-seem-to-be-a-good-question-to-me)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[China Syndrome](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078966/) was released in 1979 about 2 weeks before a similar nuclear accident at 3 Mile Island, Harrisburg, PA.

Comment: @wbogacz: Changed question in response to discussion on meta here (http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/335/this-just-doesnt-seem-to-be-a-good-question-to-me)

Comment: *The China Syndrome* contained Jack Lemmon's only death scene in his entire career, 22 years before the actor actually died.

Answer (score 20):

Though not strictly a movie, there is the now infamous example of the pilot episode of the X-Files spin-off show, [The Lone Gunmen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=z3WW6eoLcLI#!).

Airing 6 months before the terrorist attack on 9/11, it depicts the hackers foiling an attempt by a shady organization to fly a plane into the WTC in order to catalyze a Mid-East attack.

Dodgy conspiracy theories aside, this is a prime example of the entertainment media prophesizing a real event/disaster.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that. But since it's not a nature-caused disaster, I think it's less prophecy and rather a proof that terrorist watch US TV-shows ;)

Comment: @ChristianRau except that Khalid Shaikh Mohammed first presented the idea of the Sept. 11 attacks to Osama bin Laden in 1996.

Comment: @nobby: Changed question in response to discussion on meta here (http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/335/this-just-doesnt-seem-to-be-a-good-question-to-me)

Answer (score 3):

Well a few months after the film [Outbreak](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114069/) was released there was an outbreak of the  Ebola virus Zaire.

Comment: Changed question in response to discussion on meta here (http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/335/this-just-doesnt-seem-to-be-a-good-question-to-me)